# Branch.io disable right arrow button ("bnc.lt") on StatusBar

Tags: ios, ios9, deep-linking, branch.io

I have successful with adding Branch.io SDK for my iOS app, but facing problem with the right arrow button which says "bnc.lt", it seems like inconsistent when I click on it.

[image]

Once I click "bnc.lt" from within the app it takes me to Custom URL which is added in setting https://dashboard.branch.io/#/settings/link

and from next time onwards it always redirect me to Safari itself instead of redirecting to app.

Is there someone who are facing similar problem & got it resolved? let me know how to fix it or is there a way to disable that button itself.

Answer (score 4):

Full disclosure, currently employed at Branch.

As of iOS 9.2 (so, including 9.1 and 9.0), you can't disable the button appearing on the top right hand corner when clicking a Universal Link. This is an iOS system level feature, and by clicking it, Apple saves a preference on your phone that you do NOT want to be taken to the app, and instead, the website of the Universal Link.

In order to get around it, follow step 7 of this [guide](https://dev.branch.io/recipes/branch_universal_links/ios/#troubleshooting-universal-links). I'll paste the relevant information here:

*Universal Links can be disabled, unfortunately. If you are successfully taken into your app via a Universal Link, you’ll see “bnc.lt” (or your domain) and a forward button in the top right corner of the status bar. If you click that button, Apple will no longer activate Universal Links in the future. To re-enable Universal Links, long press on the link in Messages or Notes and choose ‘Open in «App»’.*

Comment: Is there any reason why an app wouldn't appear in the "Open In" list?

Comment: I have found out that "Open in <<My App>>" works when using the messages app. I was doing my testing using slack and our app wasn't appearing as a long press option in there. All good!

Comment: apps in debug mode won't appear in the open in <<My App>> I used Fabric to make it appear in the menu

Comment: No "Open In" option in iMessage app in ios 9.3.1, how to re-enable the links ? please help.